# option not selected angularjs select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I am trying to select an item of array in select options by using string value

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
  <select ng-model="gender" ng-options="g.vl as g.lbl for g in genders track by g.vl">

  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

JS CODE:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.genders = [ {lbl: 'Male', vl: 'male'}, {lbl: 'Female', vl: 'female'}];

  $scope.gender = 'female';
});
```

This is working fine when I remove the track by, It selects the initial value but I need to use the track by so I can use the value from DB (when used track by it selects empty option).. Any work around for this? (Without looping the options and comparing the initial value). Thanks Here is the snippet for the code http://jsbin.com/qixad/4/edit

Comment: Can you explain more why you think you need track by and what you think it is helping you accomplish?

Comment: I need  to use track by so the option value is not index of array. 
When using track by <option value="male"></option> which is **needed** . But when I remove track by the value is <option value="1"></option> Which is I **don't need**.

Comment: The main question is what do you want `gender` to be ? A string, an object ?

Comment: I want the gender to be string but it will just complicate things, so I made it object with the same properties as the options (E.G gender = { vl : 'male'} ) instead of string so it will be selected initially. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `track by` then angular will use the property identified in the track by expression to determine sameness. So to initialze gender, all you need to do is initialize it with an object that has the vl property defined:

```
$scope.gender = {vl:'female'}; //OR
$scope.gender = $scope.genders[1];
```

And in addition, the key in the ng-options expression must be the model itself.

```
<select ng-model="gender" ng-options="g as g.lbl for g in genders track by g.vl">
</select>
```

[JS Bin Demo](http://jsbin.com/qutixeju/3/edit)

Comment: yeah this is the solution I did... Thanks for your answer though. Hope this will help others with the same problem.

Comment: According to the `ngOptions` expression, `gender` will be bound to `g.vl` (nit an object, byt a string). The above solution (initially setting `gender` to an object) is **not** correct without further modifications.

Comment: @ExpertSystem, Forgot to specify that the model must be specified as the key in the ng-options expression. Thanks for the slight correction.

Comment: How does track by $index have to do with determining sameness between the model?

Comment: $index is special. Its position in the array determines its identity.

Comment: I see progress here :) Now the problem with the first alternative is that the original object is not the same as the one that would be selected from the select (the former contains a `vl` property only, the latter would contain a `vl` and `lbl` property). It might not be important in this particular case, but it is very likly to lead to unexpected bugs.